# GA4 Landing Page using Page Location shows error and no data

Tags: google-analytics

We are transitioning from GA Universal to GA4 and the problem we are having is we track 2 domains and we've enabled Cross Domains and have added the 2 domains following Googles doc here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en

The problem we have is that we need to be able to see the domains for the pages visited otherwise homepage visits simply show up as / with no distinction of which domain it is for.

I read that using the Page Location Dimension for reports, this will now show the full URL including domain, but Analytics shows 0 data and an error :
*Incompatible request
A request you made contains an incompatible combination of dimensions, metrics, or both, which has resulted in some data not being shown.*

GA Universal lets us see the full url with domains, and we need the same for GA4, otherwise we can't track which domain and page they are actually on.

We have not created any custom reports, simply using the Engagement->Landing Page report which we've added the Page Location Dimension.

Thanks

We added the Page Location Dimension, but that resulted in no data and Analytics giving an error of incompatible data, even though this Dimension is available as an option (others are grayed out)